# Create a variable from a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a list of databases:

```
create table tbldatabases (dblist varchar(100))
insert into tbldatabases values ('butler')
insert into tbldatabases values ('carmen')
```

In each of the listed database I have a table (tblvolume):

```
create table butler..tblvolume (volume int, Share varchar(100))
insert into butler..tblvolume values (10, 'NorthSide')
insert into butler..tblvolume values (20, 'SouthSide')
insert into butler..tblvolume values (14, 'EastSide')
insert into butler..tblvolume values (8, 'West')
```

I need to grab the max(volume) from each database..tblvolume and insert into a new table:

I have a "while" loop built, but I can't get the database variable to work to capture the max(volume) for each database.

In short, something like this:

```
declare @mindb varchar(100)=(select min(dblist) from dbs)  --Butler
declare @maxvolume int=(select max(volume) from @mindb..tblvolume)  --this is the row that won't work--
insert into myNEWtable (volume) select @mindb, @maxvolume
```

I've tried Dynamic, but still can't get it to work.  This script will give me a max(volume) 20 for butler...tblvolume.

```
declare @mindb varchar(100)=(select min(dblist) from tbldatabases)
declare @maxvolume nvarchar(500)
set @maxvolume='(select max(volume) from ' + @mindb + '..tblvolume)'
exec (@maxvolume)
```

But I can't figure out a way to do anything with the results of 20. In this case, the bottom 'select' row only outputs the text "(select max(volume) from butler..tblvolume)" instead of the value of 20.

```
declare @mindb varchar(100)=(select min(dblist) from tbldatabases)
declare @maxvolume nvarchar(500)
set @maxvolume='(select max(volume) from ' + @mindb + '..tblvolume)'
exec (@maxvolume)

insert into mytable
select @mindb, @maxvolume
```

Any idea how to adjust my script?  I'm hoping the bottom row:
select @mindb, @maxvolume

would translate to:
select Butler, 20

Comment: Sounds like the easiest for you would be to `insert...exec`. You can use the result of `exec` directly into an `insert`.

Comment: I would write some dynamic sql to build a query to select each value unioned together and directly insert the results.

Answer (score 0):

Using `INSERT...EXEC` it should work with something like this:

```
WHILE 1=1 BEGIN
    declare @mindb varchar(100)=(
        select min(dblist) from tbldatabases
        WHERE dblist NOT IN (SELECT dbname FROM dbo.mytable)
    )
    IF @mindb IS NULL BREAK
    declare @maxvolume nvarchar(500)
    set @maxvolume='select '+QUOTENAME(@mindb,'''')
            +', max(volume) from ' + QUOTENAME(@mindb) + '..tblvolume'
    PRINT @maxvolume
    INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (dbname, maxvolume)
    EXEC(@maxvolume)
END
```